# Why can't I target for .net 4.8 in my new project and why can't I choose folders where .exe file will be?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I created a new project. I have 2 problems already.

The newest .net framework available is .net framework 4.8 right?

I cannot select that

[image]

I want my .exe file to show up on this folder

[image]

Instead, the .exe file show up in this

[image]

Note: I censored the username actually, but you got the point. It shows up at \net5.0-windows instead

I want that to show up on `arbitrage2` folder straight. Not on `arbitrange2\net5.0-windows`

My other projects do not have this problem.

Where should I change this?

Also I suspect the problems are related. That's because my other project can have target framework 4.8. In fact, in other projects, .net 5.0 and .net 6.0 is not available

[image]

Comment: where did you download .net framework 4.8? you should install it in the visual studio installer, also the folder from which the .exe will be outputted should be on the Build tab on the Project properties

Comment: I forgot where I downloaded .net framework 4.8. It's available in other projects though.

Where is the build tab on project properties? I already show you project properties window I think. There is no build tab.

Comment: You picked the wrong project template to get started.  You must select one that has "(.NET Framework)" in its name.  Specifically, since you seem to try to create a Winforms project, choose "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)".  It is further down the list.

Comment: Wow. So can I change that? Or do I have to create a new project.

Comment: @HansPassant your answer was precisely what I just realized I was doing incorrectly. Cheers!